# Draw another image on a UIImage

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage, drawing

Is it possible to add another, smaller, image to a UIImage/UIImageView? If so, how? If not, then how can I draw a small filled triangle?

Thanks

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You could add a subview to your `UIImageView` containing another image with the small filled triangle. Or you could draw inside of the first image:

```
CGFloat width, height;
UIImage *inputImage;    // input image to be composited over new image as example

// create a new bitmap image context at the device resolution (retina/non-retina)
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(width, height), YES, 0.0);        

// get context
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();       

// push context to make it current 
// (need to do this manually because we are not drawing in a UIView)
UIGraphicsPushContext(context);                             

// drawing code comes here- look at CGContext reference
// for available operations
// this example draws the inputImage into the context
[inputImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height)];

// pop context 
UIGraphicsPopContext();                             

// get a UIImage from the image context- enjoy!!!
UIImage *outputImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

// clean up drawing environment
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

This code ([source here](http://www.codza.com/creating-and-drawing-on-a-new-uiimage)) will create a new `UIImage` that you can use to initialize a `UIImageView`.

Answer (score 31):

You can try this, works perfect for me, it's UIImage category:

```
- (UIImage *)drawImage:(UIImage *)inputImage inRect:(CGRect)frame {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.size, NO, 0.0);
    [self drawInRect:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.size.width, self.size.height)];
    [inputImage drawInRect:frame];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}
```

or Swift:

```
extension UIImage {
    func image(byDrawingImage image: UIImage, inRect rect: CGRect) -> UIImage! {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size)
        draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height))
        image.draw(in: rect)
        let result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return result
    }
}
```

Comment: This works well, thank you. I suggest you use 'UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0)', though. This will give you an image with the correct resolution for the screen. (The default will only produce a x1 image, which will almost certainly be blurry.)