# How to take a screen snapshot that includes a briefly-added view that the user never sees?

Tags: ios

I'm taking screen captures like this:

```
UIView *snapshot = [[UIScreen mainScreen] snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:YES];
```

Is there any way I could place something on the screen (like by adding a `UIView`), take a snapshot as above that includes this item, and then remove this item, in such a way that the user never actually sees the briefly-added item?

Comment: You could render the snapshot view to an image context, then render your extra view onto that image context giving you the composite image you want.

Comment: @rmaddy: well, that's not really what I'm trying to do here. As a side note, though, the thing returned by `snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates` is not a "real" iOS `UIView` - any attempt to take a snapshot of it (by any means) just gives you solid black.

Comment: do you want to just capture the view which have objects,Does the captured screen shot will display all elements/objects or visible objects which are on the view.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to take the screenshot and then copy that *something* in after you do the screenshot.

Hopefully that something is something that has static content, and that way you won't have to make something's UIView visible.  You can use a technique [like one that is described in this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6656745/draw-another-image-on-a-uiimage).

Comment: Unfortunately, I need a snapshot of the status bar specifically. I'm attempting to show the status bar, get a snapshot of it and then hide it again without the user's ever seeing it. I think I'm on a fool's errand.

Comment: maybe you can take a screenshot of the status bar at a *different* time (e.g. when the app first launches, before you programatically hide it) and then save the status bar screenshot to clip and paste it over your new screenshot?