# how to take a picture with overlayed logo and save it to camera roll

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

how can i implement the following:

I want an app that has a button which calls an iPhone native camera with my logo overplayed on it. and then after capturing the photo it saves it ti camera roll with the overplayed logo. Please help me .

Answer (score 1):

Open UIImagePickerController, add the logo to its view. Once the picture is taken overlay the logo upon it (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6656745/draw-another-image-on-a-uiimage) how to do that). Then save this new image to the camera roll