# iOS image blending like Fused app

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics, cgcontext, core-image

I want to blend two UIImages as Fused App is doing:

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/fused-double-exposure-video/id869117407?mt=8

What Fused is doing, it takes two images (foreground & background) and apply blending in such a way that background remains the same and user can move,rotate & size the foreground image. I attached two images for better understanding. I want to achieve the same behaviour in my app. I have tried all CoreImage & CoreGraphics but I could not achieve this. Help needed from all of you.

**First Screen:** After applying Overly blend mode.

[image: Image After Blending!]

**Second Screen:** Change the size of foreground image:

[image: Image after arranging the foreground image]

**My Result:**
[image: Screenshot of the app]

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want by using [CHTStickerView](https://github.com/chiahsien/CHTStickerView), I've used it before and it works great. `CHTStickerView` is a movable, resizable, rotatable UIView with one finger, which is fully customizable.

Use `CHTStickerView` as your foreground image and `UIImageView` as your background image.

So your code should look something like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];

  //background
  UIImageView *backgroundImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
  [backgroundImageView setImage:@"background.png"];
  [self.view addSubview:backgroundImageView];

  //foreground
  UIImageView *foregroundImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 150)];
  [foregroundImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"foreground.png"]];

  CHTStickerView *stickerView = [[CHTStickerView alloc] initWithContentView:foregroundImageView]; //set your foreground image as content in CHTStickerView
  stickerView.center = self.view.center;
  stickerView.delegate = self;
  [stickerView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Close"] forHandler:CHTStickerViewHandlerClose];
  [stickerView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Rotate"] forHandler:CHTStickerViewHandlerRotate];
  [self.view addSubview:stickerView];
}
```

**UPDATE**

Alright I downloaded the app and checked out blend. I think what the app is doing is just getting the opacity value of the foreground image with the slide bar and drawing the foreground image (opacity set) on the background image.

So to set the opacity of a UIImage check this out: [How to set the opacity/alpha of a UIImage?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10819117/2053537)

And to draw and image over another check this out: [Draw another image on a UIImage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6656766/2053537)

To summarize, what you need to do is:

1) get the position and size of the `CHTStickerView` after user rotated and resize

2) get the `UIImage` from `CHTStickerView`, get the opacity value from slider

3) set opacity to image and draw image on your background image

Hope this helps!

Comment: actually this is not the issue. My issue is about image blending. I will be very thankful to you if you can suggest a solution about this.

Comment: I attached the screenshot of my app too. So you will get a brief understanding what I want to achieve.

Comment: @MuhammadJunaidButt so you want to draw foreground image on background image?

Comment: I want to blend two images like Fused app is doing. I attached three images in my question for more convenience. Fused app blend two images and resultant image stored in foreground image. Surprising thing is that if you move/rotate/scale the foreground image, blend effect will remain the same and foreground image does not have the image of background but have the color reflection. If possible please check the screenshots and also play with Fused App (https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/fused-double-exposure-video/id869117407?mt=8). I'm stuck in this issue and have burnt my 10 days on it.

Comment: @MuhammadJunaidButt I checked out the app and its quite simple. Check out my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks to proactively answer my questions. Unfortunately, this is not the solution that I'm looking for. Can you perform a test scenario for me?
1) Use Fused app and select background & foreground images
2) Apply Overlay blend mode
3) Then select the arrange button and you will be able to change the size of foreground image.
As per my knowledge, blend applies on two images and resultant will be a single image. Fused app is applying blend but its resultant image can be resized and it also does not have the reflection of background image.

Comment: Please check my app screenshot that is the last screenshot and you will see the small image that is the blend of background & foreground image and I resized it but it does not have the same effect as Fused app has. Fused app does not have the reflection of background image but it perfectly applies the blend. Please help me in this regard.