# How can I draw an image onto of another UIImage to create one UIImage

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

I am trying to do this exact example: [Draw another image on a UIImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6656745/draw-another-image-on-a-uiimage) but in Swift.

I would greatly appreciate any explanation or any help in the right direction to do so.

Comment: what you tried in swift?

Comment: Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45915767/6536841). Thanks !!!

Answer (score 2):

This is the same code from the article but in swift hope this works for you :

```
var width: CGFloat
var height: CGFloat
var inputImage: UIImage

    // input image to be composited over new image as example
// create a new bitmap image context at the device resolution (retina/non-retina)
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(width, height), true, 0.0)
    // get context
var context: CGContextRef = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    // push context to make it current 
    // (need to do this manually because we are not drawing in a UIView)
UIGraphicsPushContext(context)
// drawing code comes here- look at CGContext reference
// for available operations
// this example draws the inputImage into the context
inputImage.drawInRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height))
// pop context 
UIGraphicsPopContext()
    // get a UIImage from the image context- enjoy!!!
var outputImage: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
// clean up drawing environment
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

Comment: I find this website useful for converting objective-c code to swift code : https://objectivec2swift.com/#/home/converter/